# How to count the number of zeros at the start of a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

```
"0011HelloWor00ld001"
```

How do I count the number of zeros in the starting of the string?
For example, the above string should return 2.

I tried `.match(/^[0]+/).size` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need `"0011HelloWor00ld001"[/^0+/].size`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.match(/^0+/)` will return a MatchData object, and thus you get `1` as the result (it denotes the number of elements in the match array).

You need to get the size of the match itself. Use  one of the following:

```
"0011HelloWor00ld001".match(/^0+/)[0].size
"0011HelloWor00ld001"[/^0+/].size
"0011HelloWor00ld001".match(/^0+/).to_s.size
```

Comment: I've noticed you often use the end-of-line anchors `^` and `$` where others might use the send-of-string anchors `\A` and `\z`. As that's obviously intentional, I'm curious to know what your thinking is about that.

Comment: If you mean me, I used OP code. I only focused on the main problem. Surely to match a *string* start one should use `\A` in Ruby.

Comment: `^` and `$` are much older and more common, so they're seen more often. In the years I've been programming I've only needed to use `\A` or `\z` instead of `^`/`$` a couple times. Most of the time I'm searching a string containing a single line so it would make no difference and I fall back to what comes to mind first.

Answer (score 4):

You could also simply use the `index` method of String like

```
str = '0011HelloWor00ld001'
# as noted by @steenslag if the full string is zeros index will return nil
# solve by returning full string length
str.index(/[^0]/) || str.length 
#=> 2
```

Comment: Interesting approach, although it might not be obvious that the index of the first non-`0` is equivalent to the number of leading `0`s.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Wiktor's middle answer best, but here are three more.

**#1**

```
def nbr_leading_zeros(str)
  str.split(/[^0]/).first.size
end

nbr_leading_zeros '0011Hello00'    #=> 2
nbr_leading_zeros '101'            #=> 0
nbr_leading_zeros '000'            #=> 3
```

**#2**

```
def nbr_leading_zeros(str)
  str.each_char.take_while { |c| c=='0' }.size
end
```

**#3**

```
def nbr_leading_zeros(str)
  str.match(/\A0*/)&.end(0).to_i
end
```

Comment: I wrote `.first` initially, too,  but it was already a long list. :)